# examdesign choices in two columns

Tags: multicol, examdesign

There is no option for displaying choices in multiple columns.

I tried to use multicol package but I couldn't make it.

How can we display choices in separate columns like this:

```
(a) Choice1      (b) Choice2
(c) Choice3      (d) Choice4
```

Here is an `examdesign` sample (Taken from this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252961/examdesign-spacing-in-two-column)):

```
\documentclass[twocolumns]{examdesign} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\NoRearrange
\NoKey 
\ContinuousNumbering

\class{Class Name}
\examname{Exam Name}
\def\namedata{Name: \hrulefill \\[4pt] Block: \hrulefill \, Date: \hrulefill}

\parindent 0ex
\begin{document}

\begin{multiplechoice}[title={Multiple-Choice}, examcolumns=2]
Directions

  \begin{question}
    Question
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{3}
    \choice{4}
  \end{question}

  \begin{question}
    Question
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{3}
    \choice{4}
  \end{question}

  \begin{question}
    Question
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{3}
    \choice{4}
  \end{question}

\begin{question}
\lipsum[4]
  I. Statement I \\[0.5em]  
  II. Statement2 \\[0.5em]  
  III. Statement3 \\
    \choice{I only}
    \choice{II only}
    \choice{III only}
    \choice[!]{I, II, and III}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Question
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{3}
    \choice{4}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
\lipsum[4]
  I. Statement I \\[0.5em]  
  II. Statement2 \\[0.5em]  
  III. Statement3 \\
    \choice{I only}
    \choice{II only}
    \choice{III only}
    \choice[!]{I, II, and III}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Question
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{3}
    \choice{4}
\end{question}

\end{multiplechoice}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If a package doesn't support an option you have to have, it is generally easier to use another package or none at all.  That way you will spend more time learning to use LaTeX and less learning how to use a particular package.

Comment: Looking at the source code, I see that examdesign does its own parsing, which means it is not going to recognized LaTeX instructions outside text fields.  Exam class will do what you want and is more current (2015 vs 2001).